# Laravel with firebase (A message can only have one of the following targets: condition, token, topic, unknown)

Tags: laravel, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is the message error:

```json
{
    "message": "A message can only have one of the following targets: condition, token, topic, unknown",
    "exception": "NotificationChannels\\Fcm\\Exceptions\\CouldNotSendNotification",
    "file": "/app/vendor/laravel-notification-channels/fcm/src/Exceptions/CouldNotSendNotification.php",
    "line": 13,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/app/vendor/laravel-notification-channels/fcm/src/FcmChannel.php",
            "line": 84,
            "function": "serviceRespondedWithAnError",
            "class": "NotificationChannels\\Fcm\\Exceptions\\CouldNotSendNotification",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php",
            "line": 148,
            "function": "send",
            "class": "NotificationChannels\\Fcm\\FcmChannel",
            "type": "->"
        },
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to updates to the PHP firebase packages. I was using the versions described bellow when it was working:

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| kreait/firebase-php | 6.3.1 |
| kreait/firebase-tokens | 3.0 |
| google/cloud-storage | v1.27.0 |
| google/cloud-core | v1.45.0 |

If I update the packages from my app the notifications break with the same error message you described. Try going back the older versions listed above.

Comment: This is a known issue with the FCM library and `kreait/firebase-php` version `6.4.0`. The fix is in https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/fcm/pull/116, but until it is released, going back to 6.3.1 should help.